# How can I send complex params to asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, extjs, extjs3

all
My software struct is Extjs3.4.1 + Asp.net Mvc3.
Now I want send object from client to server

Below is javascript code:

```
Ext.getCmp("hiddenform").getForm().submit({
   method: 'POST',
   waitTitle: 'Connecting',
   timeout: 180,
   waitMsg: 'Sending data...',
   params: Ext.util.JSON.encode({ ids: [{ id: 11 },{ id: 12},{ id: 13}]}),
   url: myroot + 'stock/ObjectReceive',
   success: function (form, action) {
        Ext.Msg.alert("success", "success", function () {
              pwforqueryconditions.hide();
        });
                                },
        failure: function (form, action) {
              itemform.getForm().reset();
        });
```

And below is code on server side

```
public class IdStruct
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult ObjectReceive(List<IdStruct> ids)
{
   return Content("{success:true}");
}
```

The result is method ObjectReceive excuted,but ids is nothing

My question is how can I send complex params to asp.net

Comment: You can send them in the body of your request.

Answer (score 1):

The javascript code is fine. You just have to modify the Server side code. From my understanding, when you are sending the following data:

```
params: Ext.util.JSON.encode({ ids: [{ id: 11 },{ id: 12},{ id: 13}]})
```

The server side take it as your are sending an object (Form Data) that contains the **List/Array of ids**.

So at Server side, you have to receive it as a Single Object having List/Array of ids as property. i.e.

```
public class IdStruct
{
    public List<int> id { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult ObjectReceive(IdStruct ids)
{
   return Content("{success:true}");
}
```

Comment: sorry, I still got nothing